# Variable of type Double not computing with Double Values

Tags: casting, double, progressdialog

I have this code:

```
partialProg = 100 * ((i+1) / len);
Log.i(null, "100 * (" + (i+1) + "/" + len + ")" );
Log.i(null, "" + (int) partialProg + " <- int cast    original double -> " + partialProg);
```

where `partialProg` is a double, initialized to 1.0 as a global variable.  `partialProg` is used to compute the progress in a lengthy upload process (`len` being the amount of data points to upload, and `i` being the current data point the loop is at).  Logically, this is correct.

However, my `ProgressDialog` always displays 0%, until the final iteration, in which is displays 100%.

Curious, I used Log messages to try to find the problem.  I get results like this:

```
11-22 13:21:47.714: ERROR/(3110): LOOP ENTERED: 1 accelX to check for null: -2.329
11-22 13:21:48.044: DEBUG/rapi(3110): Successful request
11-22 13:21:48.044: INFO/global(3110): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
11-22 13:21:48.064: INFO/(3110): 100 * (2/20)
11-22 13:21:48.074: INFO/(3110): 0 <- int cast    original double -> 0.0
11-22 13:21:48.104: ERROR/(3110): LOOP ENTERED: 2 accelX to check for null: -10.924
11-22 13:21:48.434: DEBUG/rapi(3110): Successful request
11-22 13:21:48.434: INFO/global(3110): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
11-22 13:21:48.454: INFO/(3110): 100 * (3/20)
11-22 13:21:48.454: INFO/(3110): 0 <- int cast    original double -> 0.0
11-22 13:21:48.484: ERROR/(3110): LOOP ENTERED: 3 accelX to check for null: -8.281
11-22 13:21:48.664: DEBUG/rapi(3110): Successful request
11-22 13:21:48.674: INFO/global(3110): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
11-22 13:21:48.694: INFO/(3110): 100 * (4/20)
11-22 13:21:48.694: INFO/(3110): 0 <- int cast    original double -> 0.0
11-22 13:21:48.754: ERROR/(3110): LOOP ENTERED: 4 accelX to check for null: -2.438
11-22 13:21:49.334: DEBUG/rapi(3110): Successful request
11-22 13:21:49.334: INFO/global(3110): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
11-22 13:21:49.334: INFO/(3110): 100 * (5/20)
11-22 13:21:49.334: INFO/(3110): 0 <- int cast    original double -> 0.0
11-22 13:21:49.364: ERROR/(3110): LOOP ENTERED: 5 accelX to check for null: -9.657
11-22 13:21:49.554: DEBUG/rapi(3110): Successful request
11-22 13:21:49.554: INFO/global(3110): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
11-22 13:21:49.554: INFO/(3110): 100 * (6/20)
11-22 13:21:49.554: INFO/(3110): 0 <- int cast    original double -> 0.0
11-22 13:21:49.584: ERROR/(3110): LOOP ENTERED: 6 accelX to check for null: 7.042
11-22 13:21:49.653: DEBUG/rapi(3110): Successful request
11-22 13:21:49.653: INFO/global(3110): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
11-22 13:21:49.653: INFO/(3110): 100 * (7/20)
11-22 13:21:49.653: INFO/(3110): 0 <- int cast    original double -> 0.0
11-22 13:21:49.694: ERROR/(3110): LOOP ENTERED: 7 accelX to check for null: -6.347
11-22 13:21:49.814: DEBUG/rapi(3110): Successful request
11-22 13:21:49.814: INFO/global(3110): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
11-22 13:21:49.814: INFO/(3110): 100 * (8/20)
11-22 13:21:49.824: INFO/(3110): 0 <- int cast    original double -> 0.0
11-22 13:21:49.844: ERROR/(3110): LOOP ENTERED: 8 accelX to check for null: -15.663
11-22 13:21:49.973: DEBUG/rapi(3110): Successful request
11-22 13:21:49.973: INFO/global(3110): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
11-22 13:21:49.973: INFO/(3110): 100 * (9/20)
11-22 13:21:49.973: INFO/(3110): 0 <- int cast    original double -> 0.0
11-22 13:21:50.013: ERROR/(3110): LOOP ENTERED: 9 accelX to check for null: -1.771
11-22 13:21:50.143: DEBUG/rapi(3110): Successful request
11-22 13:21:50.143: INFO/global(3110): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
11-22 13:21:50.143: INFO/(3110): 100 * (10/20)
11-22 13:21:50.154: INFO/(3110): 0 <- int cast    original double -> 0.0
11-22 13:21:50.174: ERROR/(3110): LOOP ENTERED: 10 accelX to check for null: 12.326
11-22 13:21:50.304: DEBUG/rapi(3110): Successful request
11-22 13:21:50.304: INFO/global(3110): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
11-22 13:21:50.304: INFO/(3110): 100 * (11/20)
11-22 13:21:50.304: INFO/(3110): 0 <- int cast    original double -> 0.0
11-22 13:21:50.324: ERROR/(3110): LOOP ENTERED: 11 accelX to check for null: -1.553
11-22 13:21:50.434: DEBUG/rapi(3110): Successful request
11-22 13:21:50.434: INFO/global(3110): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
11-22 13:21:50.444: INFO/(3110): 100 * (12/20)
11-22 13:21:50.444: INFO/(3110): 0 <- int cast    original double -> 0.0
11-22 13:21:50.474: ERROR/(3110): LOOP ENTERED: 12 accelX to check for null: 3.895
11-22 13:21:50.584: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3110): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 7642 objects / 590016 bytes in 95ms
11-22 13:21:50.684: DEBUG/rapi(3110): Successful request
11-22 13:21:50.684: INFO/global(3110): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
11-22 13:21:50.694: INFO/(3110): 100 * (13/20)
11-22 13:21:50.694: INFO/(3110): 0 <- int cast    original double -> 0.0
11-22 13:21:50.704: ERROR/(3110): LOOP ENTERED: 13 accelX to check for null: 3.895
11-22 13:21:50.814: DEBUG/rapi(3110): Successful request
11-22 13:21:50.814: INFO/global(3110): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
11-22 13:21:50.824: INFO/(3110): 100 * (14/20)
11-22 13:21:50.824: INFO/(3110): 0 <- int cast    original double -> 0.0
11-22 13:21:50.844: ERROR/(3110): LOOP ENTERED: 14 accelX to check for null: 6.320
11-22 13:21:51.033: DEBUG/rapi(3110): Successful request
11-22 13:21:51.033: INFO/global(3110): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
11-22 13:21:51.033: INFO/(3110): 100 * (15/20)
11-22 13:21:51.033: INFO/(3110): 0 <- int cast    original double -> 0.0
11-22 13:21:51.064: ERROR/(3110): LOOP ENTERED: 15 accelX to check for null: -3.868
11-22 13:21:51.164: DEBUG/rapi(3110): Successful request
11-22 13:21:51.164: INFO/global(3110): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
11-22 13:21:51.164: INFO/(3110): 100 * (16/20)
11-22 13:21:51.164: INFO/(3110): 0 <- int cast    original double -> 0.0
11-22 13:21:51.194: ERROR/(3110): LOOP ENTERED: 16 accelX to check for null: -9.820
11-22 13:21:51.304: DEBUG/rapi(3110): Successful request
11-22 13:21:51.304: INFO/global(3110): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
11-22 13:21:51.314: INFO/(3110): 100 * (17/20)
11-22 13:21:51.314: INFO/(3110): 0 <- int cast    original double -> 0.0
11-22 13:21:51.324: ERROR/(3110): LOOP ENTERED: 17 accelX to check for null: -5.530
11-22 13:21:51.454: DEBUG/rapi(3110): Successful request
11-22 13:21:51.454: INFO/global(3110): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
11-22 13:21:51.464: INFO/(3110): 100 * (18/20)
11-22 13:21:51.464: INFO/(3110): 0 <- int cast    original double -> 0.0
11-22 13:21:51.474: ERROR/(3110): LOOP ENTERED: 18 accelX to check for null: -2.601
11-22 13:21:51.583: DEBUG/rapi(3110): Successful request
11-22 13:21:51.583: INFO/global(3110): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
11-22 13:21:51.583: INFO/(3110): 100 * (19/20)
11-22 13:21:51.594: INFO/(3110): 0 <- int cast    original double -> 0.0
11-22 13:21:51.614: ERROR/(3110): LOOP ENTERED: 19 accelX to check for null: -6.020
11-22 13:21:52.043: DEBUG/dalvikvm(767): GC_EXPLICIT freed 347 objects / 19880 bytes in 129ms
11-22 13:21:52.054: DEBUG/rapi(3110): Successful request
11-22 13:21:52.054: INFO/global(3110): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
11-22 13:21:52.054: INFO/(3110): 100 * (20/20)
11-22 13:21:52.054: INFO/(3110): 100 <- int cast    original double -> 100.0
11-22 13:21:52.354: WARN/IInputConnectionWrapper(3110): finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
```

You can see that it says that `partialProg` is always 0, which I assume is because it is multiplying some decimal number < 1 by 100.  But, it's of type double!  Why would it be doing that?
I even tried typecasting it in a lot of places to a double - with no different results.

Any ideas of what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter how you initialize `partialProg`, since you immediately overwrite it.

What matters is the *type* of the expression `100 * ((i+1) / len);`, which is an *integer* in your case (assuming `i` and `len` are integers). Consequently, the *value* of the expression is constrained to integral values.

To make an expression of type `double`, just make the individial terms into doubles. For example:

```
100.0 * double(i + 1) / double(len);
```

Comment: @MikeGates: Well, any given expression has to have the right type. If you're unsure, making *everything* double is the safe way to go :-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify your language, so I tested this in Java.

I see your issue when I have the **len** variable defined as an `int`. When I switch it to a `double`, it works as expected.